# Make JFileChooser.showSaveDialog look more like showOpenDialog

Tags: java, swing, osx-yosemite

Can I make JFileChooser show a save dialog that looks like the open dialog if I use the setAccessory method and then handle accessory events? As an example, can I make my save dialog look like the one for Pages version 5.5.3?

When I execute JFileChooser.showOpenDialog on OS X Yosemite, the shown dialog looks exactly like an OS X Finder dialog (e.g., the Sidebar is shown if preferred). In fact, if I alter the Finder preferences and then I create a JFileChooser, the open dialog reflects the changes I made to Finder's preferences.

When I execute showSaveDialog a less helpful dialog is shown. I would like showSaveDialog to have a superset of showOpenDialog components.

This next image is what my application shows when it calls showOpenDialog.

[image: application's showOpenDialog]

Here is what my application shows when it calls showSaveDialog.

[image: application's showSaveDialog]

And here is what Apple's word processing app, Pages, shows when you ask to save a file. This is what I want my app to show. And as I started to explain above, I think I can do it if I add an accessory to the dialog, set the layout of the components in the dialog, and then handle events appropriately.

[image: Pages save file dialog]

Comment: As an aside, what Look and Feel is the app. using?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's Apple's version of Microsoft's Word. I put in the version of Pages in the event that some other version does not behave like the one I have. Being relatively new to Swing, I cannot answer that question. I believe it would be the default, however there are components of the app that use macwidgets2. Looks like I now have enough reputation to add screenshots. I couldn't earlier but forgot to recheck.

Comment: Screenshots would be helpful.  See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: Which look and feel the application is using? You can get it by adding `        System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel());` to your main.

Comment: @KDM  [Aqua Look and Feel for Mac OS X - com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel]

Comment: @jeff6times7 I am trying with a sample program on Yosemite with JDK 8, I get the same window for both open and save. That looks like your save dialog. The look and feel is the same.

Comment: @KDM Looks like I'll have to create my own sscce, like I should have done from the start. I'm using JDK 7 u 75 but I'll try with JDK 8 too.

Comment: I thought the application was using JFileChooser for both opening and saving files. I was wrong. The application is using JFileDialog for opening files and JFileChooser for saving files. I was misled by an abstracting class. Sorry everyone.